# How can i send multiple information from a client application to a server?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, server, client

I'm new in regards to sockets and I would like to know how can i take what is written in several textfields from the client application and put that data into labels located in the Server application depending on the textfield that they come from.

So far I made the connection between the client and the server and when you press the button in the client class you can send the string from the textfield and succesfully write that in the label located in the server class.

Here I have the Client class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JTextField field1;
    JTextField field2;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton btnStart;
    JLabel lblText;

    public Client(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        lblText=new JLabel("CLIENT");
        lblText.setBounds(75,0,150,30);
        field1=new JTextField(20);
        field1.setBounds(10,40,225,30);
        field2=new JTextField(20);
        field2.setBounds(10,80,225,30);
        btnStart=new JButton("Send");
        btnStart.setBounds(75,100,75,30);
        btnStart.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(btnStart);
        panel.add(field1);
        panel.add(field2);
        panel.add(lblText);

        this.add(panel);
        this.setBounds(600,300,275,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource() == this.btnStart){
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.90",9000);
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF(field1.getText());
                out.close();
                field1.setText("");/*
                DataOutputStream out2 = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out2.writeUTF(field2.getText());
                out2.close();
                */
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Connection failed");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Server class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Server extends JFrame implements Runnable{
  JLabel lblUsername;
  JLabel lblNss;
  JPanel panel;
  Thread thread1;

  public Server(){
    panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        lblUsername = new JLabel("");
    lblUsername.setBounds(0,0,150,30);
    lblNss = new JLabel("");
    lblNss.setBounds(0,40,150,30);
    panel.add(lblUsername);panel.add(lblNss);

    thread1 = new Thread(this);
    thread1.start();


        this.add(panel);
    this.setBounds(1200,300,280,350);
        this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
  public void run(){
    try {
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9000); 
      while(true){
        Socket socket = server.accept(); 
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String text_message = in.readUTF();
        lblUsername.setText(text_message);
        //lblNss.setText();
        socket.close();
      }
    }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: My fault, i translated the post already

Comment: Your objects and variables should have english names aswell.

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt not really, as long as the description is in english, you can have your code in french if you want, but it should be compact enough to fit a [mre] so that it's easy to understand and isolate the problem. Code in english is not a must.

Comment: To send multiple Strings, you need to create your own custom object, add all the info from the text fields to it, then send the object, on the server side, use that object fields to populate the labels.

Comment: @Frakcool thanks for your feedback, it really help me to solve my problem

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider posting your own answer to the question and accept it so others with a similar problem can benefit as well from this :)

Comment: @Frakcool My comment wasnt SO-Specific. Code should always be en english. No matter if you ask a question on SO or work in a company.

Comment: It depends on the company, some companies require you to write your variables and classes with an specific pattern and sometimes they want it to be in the spoken language where the company is located, it may be Spanish, Russian, English, you name it. It may not be ideal but it happens. @MoritzSchmidt my comment wasn't SO-specific either. Not gonna discuss this in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Frakcool for the help.

"To send multiple Strings, you need to create your own custom object, add all the info from the text fields to it, then send the object, on the server side, use that object fields to populate the labels"

Here I created the custom object that would recieve the strings from the textfields

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Object extends JFrame{
  String name;
  String nss;

  public Object(String field1, String field2){
   this.name = field1;
   this.nss = field2;
  }
}
```

Here is part of the Client application, when a button is pressed you can send the info to the server

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == this.btnEnviar){
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.90",9000); // Server IP
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Object o = new Object(name.getText(),nss.getText()); //Here I would created the object based on the data from two different JTextFields
            os.writeObject(o);
            os.close();
            name.setText("");
            nss.setText("");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed");
        }

    }
}
```

So in the server you need to create the object and if needed you can store the atributtes of the object

```
public void run(){
  try {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9000);
    while(true){
      Socket socket = server.accept(); 
      ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      Objeto o = (Objeto)is.readObject();
      lblNombre.setText(o.nombre);
      lblNSS.setText(o.nss);
      socket.close();
    }
  }catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked using JAX-RS, with this you can send more than one parameter as a link in the url or even send objects. For me it was quite useful because all of the translation from Java Object to a json in the client(to send to the server) and then the translation from json to java object in the server it is transparent and easy to implement.

Here is an example of a method receiving two parameters:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/purchase/{title}/{date}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response extendPurchase(@PathParam("title") String title, @PathParam("date") String date) {
        if(DBManager.extendPurchase(title, date)) {
            return Response.ok().build();
        }else {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
    }
```

And here it is an example of a method receiving an object
This is the method in the server:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/purchase")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registerPurchase(Book book){
        if (DBManager.registerPurchase(book))
            return Response.ok().build();
        else
            return Response.serverError().build();
        
    }
```

And here called in the client:

```
    //Client and server reference
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("URL");

    //Create an object and send it to the server
    Book b = new Book();
    WebTarget wb = webTarget.path("/purchase");
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilderWB = wb.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response = invocationBuilderWB.post(Entity.entity(b,  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

I hope it is useful to you.

Comment: Hello Juan,  my code is pretty simple at the moment and actually is for a school project but i would like to understand how your code works

Comment: Sure! 
Which part would you like me to explain?

Comment: The project is in a public repo so if you want to check some part of my code feel free to do it.
https://github.com/juan-ud-santos/Deusto-Booking